# Mysql - Why does FileSort take longer than actual fetch?

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I've got an sql query running on my Mysql Database.
I've got a table with 1.5M records. I'm trying to fetch the last 50 items created ,based on the items' creators.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `items`
WHERE `items`.`owner_id`
  IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
ORDER BY `items`.`id`
  DESC LIMIT 50
```

The query is using the owner_id index, which makes sense. right?
Well apparently, using this index takes almost 3 seconds, while working with the Primary index takes a 100 milliseconds.

When running through explain I see the following:

```
1   SIMPLE  items   range   idx_owner   idx_owner   4   NULL    56  Using index condition; Using filesort
```

However when I run the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `items` FORCE INDEX(PRIMARY)
WHERE `items`.`owner_id`
  IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
ORDER BY `items`.`id`
  DESC LIMIT 50
```

I get the following explain:

```
1   SIMPLE  items   index   NULL    PRIMARY 4   NULL    50  Using where
```

Which means that I just got rid of the filesort, though I lost my index on the where clause.

The query seems to return 15,000 records (due to the in) and then sorts them and selects the last 50. 
As to my question - How is it possible that sorting 15,000 records is so less efficient than scanning a 1.5M table and searching for 15,000 records? Sorting shouldn't be such a difficult task while searching is much more difficult (without an index!) what am I missing?

Attached - indexes of table:

```
items   0   PRIMARY 1   id  A   1444298 NULL    NULL        BTREE       
items   1   items_a951d5d6  1   slug    A   288859  767 NULL        BTREE       
items   1   category_id_refs_id_3b77a81e    1   category_id A   34  NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
items   1   origin_id_refs_id_99b3fd12  1   origin_id   A   2   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
items   1   parent_id_refs_id_99b3fd12  1   parent_id   A   6   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
items   1   name    1   name    A   1444298 NULL    NULL        BTREE       
items   1   idx_owner   1   owner_id    A   722149  NULL    NULL        BTREE
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting several thousand full rows of information is not as cheap as you think. Also, notice that `filesort` doesn't necessarily mean the sorting of a file in the file system. It means that a derived table needs to be sorted.

The query you're looking at can be refactored as follows, and will very likely perform better as a result.

```
SELECT i.*
  FROM items AS i
  JOIN (
        SELECT id
          FROM items
         WHERE owner_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
         ORDER BY id DESC
         LIMIT 50
       ) AS j ON i.id = j.id
 ORDER BY i.id DESC
```

This is because your original query contains `SELECT *`. To satisfy that query MySQL has to shuffle all the columns of your table.  The subquery in this refactoring simply comes up with the fifty `id` values you want.  It still has to sort them, but sorting a bunch of integers is faster than sorting a bunch of rows.

```
        SELECT id
          FROM items
         WHERE owner_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
         ORDER BY id DESC
         LIMIT 50
```

The outer query retrieves the whole row for each of those fifty ids, which should be relatively fast.

Something to notice here.

```
WHERE owner_id BETWEEN 1 AND 8
```

is going to be easier for MySQL to satisfy than

```
WHERE owner_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

because the server can do a single range scan on your index on `owner_id`. You may not be able to use `BETWEEN` in all cases, but if you can, do.

If this query is performance critical, you might try creating a compound index on

```
(owner_id, id)
```

and see if it speeds the query up a lot.

Comment: MySQL still does range scans with `IN`, as evidenced by the `EXPLAIN` result. Also, short of a covering index, the multi-column index on `(owner_id, id)` isn't going to help unless the search is only on one owner_id. Still, a nice answer. If only MySQL were smart enough (knew our data well enough) to be able to make these types of optimizations (such as your subquery) on its own.

Comment: Just last question, I was under the impression sorting only performs the actions on the row_id (which is an integer field). Why would the amount of columns in the query then influence the sort's performance ?

Comment: Sorting has to wrangle a table -- both of key columns and the other columns being sorted. Smaller table = faster sort. The table can be made smaller either by including fewer rows or fewer columns. My advice here trades a many-row - many-column sort for a many-row one-column sort.